# String of random numbers with exclusions for each

Tags: python

How can I generate a string of 100 random numbers between 1-14 if each number has at least one number that cannot follow it? 
E.g ‘1’ cannot be followed by ‘3’ and ‘2’ cannot be followed by ‘4’or ‘9’. 
No repetitions either so ‘1’ cannot be followed immediately by another ‘1’.

Comment: This site is a repository for specific questions and answers, not a coding service.

Comment: I thought it was a specific question. I know how to generate a string of random numbers using random.choice and i’m asking how I can exclude certain numbers following other numbers. I’m new to coding and have searched everywhere for answers but am completely stuck on this.

Comment: "How do I write this program" isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting random numbers, you could use `random` module, especially `random.randint` or `random.choice`, following code will produce `100` random numbers from `1...14` range (inclusive), but without repeats:

```
numbers = [random.choice(range(1,14+1))]
while len(numbers)<100:
    lastnumber = numbers[-1]
    newnumber = random.choice([i for i in range(1,14+1) if i!=lastnumber])
    numbers.append(newnumber)
```

EDIT: Following version will prevent particular numbers from following

```
numbers = [random.choice(range(1,14+1))]
tabu = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9],[8,9,10],[9,10,11],[10,11,12],[11,12,13],[12,13,14],[13,14]]
while len(numbers)<100:
    lastnumber = numbers[-1]
    newnumber = random.choice([i for i in range(1,14+1) if not i in tabu[lastnumber-1]])
    numbers.append(newnumber)
```

There `tabu` list is containing information which numbers are prohibited after given number, however as python indexing is starting at `0` there is `tabu[lastnumber-1]`. No `1` and `2` after `1`, no `1` and `2` and `3` after `2`, no `2` and `3` and `4` after `3` and so on.

Comment: Thanks i understand this. My problem is how do I exclude certain sequences of numbers like a number one following a number 3.

Comment: Thank you so much! Tabu was exactly what I was looking for and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the previous example ( @Daweo ) by use a dictionary, which will include numbers that are not allowed to follow the previous number

`...
newnumber = random.choice([i for i in range(1,14+1) if i!=myfun(i)])`

`def myfun(i):
    i = str(i)
    abc = {'1':2 ,'2':9, '3':12...} #I'm not sure whether the keyword of the dictionary is a number, but I'm sure it will be right
    return abc[i] #will return the number that is associated with the key`

for more information see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm